# Is there any way to use np.digitize when I want to define the number of bins?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, grouping, digitization

I have big data where i have a numerical column. I simply want to convert the in a groups.

I think `pd.np.digitize( df.col, bins = [10, 20, 30]  )` could be the solution but I can't define here bins as I have high amount of values.

In my case, I want to define i.e 300 bins and then all the values should be grouped based on that... IS there any way to use np.digitize?

Comment: can't u use ```pd.cut(..,300)``` ?

Comment: yes but how i can define 300 there?

Comment: does bins = 300 not work?